# attribute error in web scraping in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Written some code to scrape a website: `https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html` but I'm getting an error:

> `Nontype object has no attribute text`

Failed to find a solution for this so how can I can fix this error?

```py
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    
    
    all_books=[]
    
    url='https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'
    headers=('https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/22526098chrome-windows-blink')
    def get_page(url):
        page=requests.get(url,headers)
        status=page.status_code
        soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
        return [soup,status]
    
    #get all books links
    def get_links(soup):
        links=[]
        listings=soup.find_all(class_='product_pod')
        for listing in listings:
            bk_link=listing.find("h3").a.get("href")
            base_url='https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'
            cmplt_link=base_url+bk_link
            links.append(cmplt_link)
        return links
        
    #extraxt info from each link
    def extract_info(links):
        for link in links:
            r=requests.get(link).text
            book_soup=BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
    
            name=book_soup.find(class_='col-sm-6 product_main').text.strip()
            price=book_soup.find(class_='col-sm-6 product_main').text.strip()
            desc=book_soup.find(class_='sub-header').text.strip()
            cat=book_soup.find('"../category/books/poetry_23/index.html">Poetry').text.strip()
            book={'name':name,'price':price,'desc':desc,'cat':cat}
            all_books.append(book)
    
    pg=48
    while True:
        url=f'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{pg}.html'
        soup_status=get_page(url)
        if soup_status[1]==200:
            print(f"scrapping page{pg}")
            extract_info(get_links(soup_status[0]))
            pg+=1
        else:
            print("The End")
            break
    
    df=pd.DataFrame(all_books)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Add the full error details please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** *First of all, always take a look at your soup - therein lies the truth. The contents can always differ slightly to extremely from the view in the dev tools.*

#### What happens?

There are different issues you should keep in mind:

- `base_url='https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'` will lead to **404 errors** and is the first reason causing your *"Nontype object has no attribute text"*
- You try to find the category like this `cat=book_soup.find('"../category/books/poetry_23/index.html">Poetry').text.strip()` what won't work to and will lead to same error
- There some more selection that will not lead to an expected result, take a look in my example edited them to give you a clue how to get the goal.

#### How to fix?

1. Change `base_url='https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'` to `base_url='https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/'`
2. Select the category more specific, it is the last `<a>` in breadcrumb:

   ```
   cat=book_soup.select('.breadcrumb a')[-1].text.strip()
   ```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


all_books=[]

url='https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'
headers=('https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/22526098chrome-windows-blink')
def get_page(url):
    page=requests.get(url,headers)
    status=page.status_code
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
    return [soup,status]

#get all books links
def get_links(soup):
    links=[]
    listings=soup.find_all(class_='product_pod')
    for listing in listings:
        bk_link=listing.find("h3").a.get("href")
        base_url='https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/'
        cmplt_link=base_url+bk_link
        links.append(cmplt_link)
    return links
    
#extraxt info from each link
def extract_info(links):
    for link in links:
        r=requests.get(link).text
        book_soup=BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
        name= name.text.strip() if (name := book_soup.h1) else None
        price= price.text.strip() if (price := book_soup.select_one('h1 + p')) else None
        desc= desc.text.strip() if (desc := book_soup.select_one('#product_description + p')) else None
        cat= cat.text.strip() if (cat := book_soup.select('.breadcrumb a')[-1]) else None
        book={'name':name,'price':price,'desc':desc,'cat':cat}
        all_books.append(book)

pg=48
while True:
    url=f'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{pg}.html'
    soup_status=get_page(url)
    if soup_status[1]==200:
        print(f"scrapping page{pg}")
        extract_info(get_links(soup_status[0]))
        pg+=1
    else:
        print("The End")
        break

all_books
```

Comment: It generates the error nontype object has no attribute text.But not in name and price. It generates error in desc.

Comment: My fault, added wrong version - Edited the example to catch this behavior `desc= desc.text.strip() if (desc := book_soup.select_one('#product_description + p')) else None
`

Comment: Thanks..It helps me very much and my code is running.

Comment: Can you help me to run the csv file of this code on heroku??

Comment: This would be predestined to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with focus on heroku and we will have a look - *Each question should address exactly one problem, to keep questions and answers clean and get best possible answers.* Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the function below when you need to grab the text of element.
It will protect you from `None` elements

```
def get_text(book_soup,clazz):
  ele = book_soup.find(class_=clazz)
  return ele.text.strip() if ele is not None else ''
```

Example.Instead of

```
    name=book_soup.find(class_='col-sm-6 product_main').text.strip()
```

do

```
    name=get_text(book_soup,'col-sm-6 product_main')
```

Comment: It helps me to get rid of 'None' but i doesn't show any output.

Comment: since some of the elements **cant be found** - the function will return an empty string.

Comment: so what help me for getting my output

Comment: it cannot found any element all elements are empty.

Comment: print `requests.get(link).text` - do you see the data you are looking for?

Comment: requests.get(link).text i have tried this but it cannot find my solution